# How do I use CreateContext for my state in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to pass state to my nested component and want to use UseContext hook what am I doing wrong as I am getting following error.

Error:
export UserContext.createContext('');
|         ^

App.JS

```
    import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";

const UserContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTask] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Doctors Appointment",
      day: "Feb 5th at 2.30pm",
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Meeting at School",
      day: "Feb 6th at 1.30pm",
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "Food Shopping",
      day: "Feb 5th at 1.30pm",
      reminder: false,
    },
  ]);

  //Delete Task
  const deleteTask = (id) => {
    setTask(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ tasks, setTask }}>
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Tasks onDelete={deleteTask} />
      </div>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
export UserContext.createContext('');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that the possible problem or a typo you have made is in your last `export` line which is explained below. The below line should be removed.

```js
// should be removed from the code
export UserContext.createContext('');
```

The `export` keyword should come before the declaration of the `UserContext` variable. It should be:

```js
export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

With this correction, the `UserContext` context can be imported and used in other parts of the application.

**Helper Link**

Also, if you'd like to learn more and how to do things right with `useContext` hooks, please see [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-for-beginners/) link. It explains the use of this hook with an export example.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I fail to understand why all the time I get negative scoring on my questions which makes me feel demotivated and disappointing.

Comment: That is a very good question my friend @user342944. Somehow StackOverflow has a set of principles, and one of them is to **have proper research before you ask**. You might ask what that means. I have certain pointers for you, please follow this link: [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will certainly help you. Thank you for your upvote. I'd also appreciate it if you can give an upvote too, as you've rightfully marked the answer as the right answer.